# run thin outside of shell

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, thin

I am using thin to run my Sinatra app but right now, when I close the shell, the server stops. Is it possible to run it as a process in the background and also see/minitor the logs like I do in shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-d` switch to start it daemonized. It'll write output to `log/thin.log` by default, or you can overwrite that with the `-l` switch. See `thin -h` for a full list of options.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris mentioned, you can daemonize it.

Another way is to use [`GNU Screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)

This way you can run your app in foreground and yet close your terminal.

When you get back into `Screen` session you have same environment,
just like when you switch terminal tabs.